# Using a custom font in storyboard in XCode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, storyboard

I want to use an icon font (so far with only one icon) in my iOS 8 Swift project. I first added the font to my project (`Add Files to “MyProject”` in the file list – and it was then added to my target). I then looked up the character's code point which was U+E600 and inserted U+E600 as a button's title in storyboard. Immediate success – the button now had a nice backspace icon in my storyboard.

However, when I run my app in the simulator, it just shows the infamous questionmark in a square icon.

I then added the following code to my view controller to see if the font was “really added”:

```
let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames()
for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
    println("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
    let names = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName as! String)
    println("Font Names = [\(names)]")
}
```

And sure enough, my font, `icomoon` appears as a single font in the font family of the same name.

I then opened `Info.plist`, figuring I might still have to add the font file manually and added `icomoon.ttf` (the filename is correct) as the first and only item in `Fonts provided by application`. Re-ran the app. Still a question mark. Ran the app on my iPhone 6 – same behaviour.

To verify that the file is included in the bundle, I opened the *Copy bundle resourced* under *Build Phases* for my target and verified that it was listed there.

The font for the button in XCode:

[image]

How it looks in the storyboard in XCode:

[image]

How it looks in the simulator:

[image]

I'm now at a loss of how to proceed. There are lots of guides that vary in how up-to-date they are, but I don't really see anything I've missed. Have I missed something? Any way to debug this issue?

Comment: Try using an IBOutlet to get a reference to the button in code and print out its UIFont. If the font isn't right then perhaps you need to set it programmatically. I see no obvious problem with the way you've setup your button and font in Interface Builder.

Comment: Excellent suggestion to print out its UIFont! Turns out the font was the system font. Adding `self.bsButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "icomoon", size: 65)` in `viewDidLoad` does not fix the issue, but if I call the same code later (tested by doing it in the button's callback function), it works(!). Hmm...

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest grabbing a `@IBOutlet` reference to the button in code and print out its `UIFont`. If the font isn't right than perhaps you need to set it programmatically:

```
yourLabel.font = UIFont(name: "icomoon", size: 20)
```

I see no problem with the way you have setup your button in interface builder, so it could be a bug or some technicality about the font name.

One thought that comes to mind is that the typical font name is in the form `FontFamily-FontName` (ex. `HelveticaNeue-Regular`), whereas your font name isn't like that. Perhaps that has something to do with it.